# Использование Context в Toast

Tags: android, java

Разбираюсь с диалогами:

```
public class Dialog2 extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    Context context;

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.exit)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, this)
                .setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel, this)
                .setMessage(R.string.save_data);
        return adb.create();
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                saveData();
                //finish();
                break;
            case Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                //finish();
                break;
            case Dialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
                break;
        }
    }

    void saveData() {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dialog 2: onDismiss");
    }

    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dialog 2: onCancel");
    }
}
```

В методе saveData() нужно вывести сообщение. Но возникает ошибка при компиляции, указывающую на единственную строчку в этом методе. Т.е. ему не нравится, что я передаю методу context, пробовал this, но всё равно ругается. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Полю `context` не присвоено значение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас не проиницилизирован context, да это и не нужно, используйте  getActivity()

Comment: Спасибо! А можно вкратце, что делает getActivity()?

Comment: [compl][1], возвращает ссылку на `Activity`, которая может быть использована в качестве контекста, поскольку является его потомком


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/19290/compl

Comment: Спасибо, понял.